# Why can't I log into Django users with valid credentials, but can log into my original superuser?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this issue in my django project where users cannot login after creating an account. The user credentials are correct so everything should be working, but I guess I forgot to properly connect something while building my Customer User Model.

Looking at my admin page, I see users in the database.
I also cannot log into a superuser version of the account (changing superuser = True) when trying to de-bug the error. I've added some recommendations I found online such as

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

in my settings, but still no success. I'm only able to log into my original super-user that I created.

Code below:

`models.py`

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        if not user_name:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide a username'))

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide your first name'))

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide your last name'))
        
        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide your last name'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name,
                          first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=password, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

urls.py

```
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/', include('bucket_api.urls', namespace='bucket_api')),
```

as you can see im trying to log into the default REST framework url AND my admin panel page, the issues persists with both except for my original superuser. I dont think this is a migration issue because there aren't any changes to migrate.

here's the GET error = `"GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 403 4997`

Comment: Did you set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to point to your `NewUser` model ? You can read more about it [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Yes I did, had that set before this issue occurred.

Comment: because when you creating user you set  is_active as default false and in admin you set as default true . django inbuilt authentication only allow login if is_active true.

Comment: @Meet, thank you for catching that, I'm still not able to solve the problem though, but I'm sure your fix will help me get closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @meet, I've solved the issue using his recommended fix. I also had to add to my `settings.py`

`rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication`

like so:

```
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
```

Doing both of these fixes solved my error.